# Web application doesn't work on Edge Browser 41

Tags: javascript, html, browser, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

I am working on Intranet web application. it has developed using Strust2 and run on the weblogic 12c server. application working on dev environment without any issue IE(11) and Edge(41) Microsoft browser.
But after deploying Production it only working IE(11).it doesn't work on Edge.we can launch login page after that but can't navigate on Edge.
Edge browser console we can see below error.

```
CSP14321 Resource violated directive 'default-src 'self'' in Content-security-Policy:inline script https://xx.xxx.x.xx/dms/login.action at line
19 column 30.Resource will be blocked
```

Note: Our Web Application supports work with IE11 and Edge.

I tried with the different approach but couldn't navigate from the login page
1.i remove the meta tags like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

2.add meta tags like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'"/>
```

above approach doesn't work.to change Content Security Policy no any configurations files in our application .plase help with this

This is the login page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ page import="tvm.ka.TvsGlobals"%>
<%@ page errorPage="/tvs/ka/common/KvsCommonError.jsp"%>


<head>
<title><s:text name="title.login" /></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strCSS%>" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" src="<%=kvsConfigMgr.strJS%>KvsCommon.js">

</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strJS%>KvsLogin.js">

</script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var MSG_USERID = "<s:text name="msg.login.userid"/>";
    var MSG_PASSWORD = "<s:text name="msg.login.password"/>";
</script>
</head>
<body background="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strLstBg%>" leftmargin="0"
    topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="focusFirst()">
    <s:form action="login" method="POST">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><div align="center">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" background="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>topbg.gif">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                        background="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>topbg.gif">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                                                    cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td width="13%"
                                                            background="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>logo_bg.jpg"><img
                                                            src="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>default_01.jpg" width="133"
                                                            height="77" alt=""></td>
                                                        <td width="87%"
                                                            background="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>top_bg.jpg"><img
                                                            src="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>default_02.jpg" width="645"
                                                            height="77" alt=""></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div align="left"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="errorText">
                    <%-- <s:if
                                        test="${not empty ${KmsGlobals.GLOBAL_ERR_MSG_LIST}.null}"
                                        scope="request">
                                        <s:iterator value="${KmsGlobals.GLOBAL_ERR_MSG_LIST}.null"
                                            indexId="count" id="errMsg" type="java.lang.String">
                                            <s:property value="errMsg.null" />
                                            <br>
                                        </s:iterator>
                                    </s:if> --%> <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
                        <div class="error">
                            <s:actionerror />
                        </div>
                    </s:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bodyTextSmall">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                        <tr>
                            <td>To begin, please key in your user id and<br />password
                                below, and click on login.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>tran.gif" width="80"
                                height="8" /></td>
                            <td><img src="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>tran.gif" width="150"
                                height="8" /></td>
                            <td><img src="<%=KvsConfigMgr.strIMG%>tran.gif" width="80"
                                height="8" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bodyTextBold">User ID</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="strUserId" size="20"
                                tabindex="1" /></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bodyTextBold">Password</td>
                            <td>
                                <%--
                   <!--html:password property="strPasswd" autocomplete="off" size="20" tabindex="2"/ -->
                         I-WAPT-8 Password autocomplete attribute was enabled
                         Application Penetration Test Fix
                  --%> <input type="password" name="strPasswd"
                                autocomplete="off" size="20" tabindex="2" />
                            </td>
                            <td><input class="button" style="width: 70px" type="submit"
                                value="Login" onClick="return validate()" tabindex="3" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="errorText">For authorised use only.
                                Unauthorised use is strictly prohibited.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%-- <s:hidden name="dispatch" value="login" /> --%>
        <input type="hidden" name="dispatch" value="login" />

    </s:form>

    <div id="version-tag"><%=KvsConfigMgr.strVer%></div>

    <style>
#version-tag {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    FONT-WEIGHT: normal;
    FONT-SIZE: 11px;
    COLOR: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    border-color: #0085E0;
}
</style>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with *content-security-policy*s you cannot use inline Javascript like `onLoad="focusFirst()"` and

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var MSG_USERID = "<s:text name="msg.login.userid"/>";
    var MSG_PASSWORD = "<s:text name="msg.login.password"/>";
</script>
```

> https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Inline Javascript code will simply not be executed.

Instead, create a Javascript file with this code:

```
document.addEventListener('load', focusFirst);
```

Make sure `focusFirst` function is known at that point.

Depending on what `focusFirst` does it might improve the performance if you instead attach the listener to the `DOMContentLoaded` event (which triggers when all HTML is parsed, whereas `load` only triggers much later once all linked resources like images etc. have been loaded).

Please note that inline `<script>` blocks will also not be executed with a *content security policy* active.

Comment: appreciate your answer, my concern is from our side we haven't config Content security policy. where it comes from and how to override.

Comment: Those rules are there for a reason (mainly to prevent cross site scripting). I wouldn't bother changing that. instead, adjust your code.